# Live object is garbage collected?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, garbage-collection

I am using Garbage collector in my Cocoa based application on Mac OS X. It has 100s of threads running and synchronization is done using Operation Queue.

After a long run, one of the object is garbaged and application will crash.

Checking to see if the object is non nil also fails as the the object is invalid and contains some garbage value. Calling a method on the object leads to crash.

Anyone please help me in debugging the issue.

Thank you......................

Comment: I'm not aware of any particular issue like this.  Can you give more information?  Maybe try to narrow down the problem some?  Post any code you suspect as causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

> I am using Garbage collector in my
>   Cocoa based application on Mac OS X.
>   It has 100s of threads running and
>   synchronization is done using
>   Operation Queue.

More likely than not, the bug lies within the seemingly rather overly concurrent nature of your code.   Running 100s of threads on a machine with "only" double digits worth of cores (if that) is unlikely to be very efficient and, of course, keeping everything properly in sync is going to be rather difficult.

The best place to start is to turn on Malloc stack logging and use `malloc_history` to find out what events occurred at the address that went south.

Also, there were fixes in 10.6.5 that impacted GC correctness.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the code of the garbage collected object, then override the finalize method like this, to get some information:

```
- (void) finalize
{
    NSLog(@"Finalizing!\n%@", [[NSThread callStackSymbols] componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]);
    //if you put here a breakpoint, you can check the supposed references to this object
    [super finalize];
}
```

Comment: The advice is good, but did you see the tag that says "Objective-C" and the absence of a tag that says "Java"?

Comment: @Peter Hosey: and I fixed the bug that `[super finalize]` was not sent.

Comment: @JeremyP: Oops! You can tell I don't ordinarily write GC code. Thanks.

Comment: What about the performance of using GC for applications that runs 100s of threads.....    Will it cost any performance

Comment: In java overriding finalize is bad practice from the perspective of garbage collector performance. As for Objective C I suppose the same. So this change is to see what the problem is